# how can I create a chapter heading like this?

Tags: formatting, pdftex, chapters, thesis

Hi I want to format my chapter of my thesis as shown in the figure. How can I do it?
Can you suggest me some fancy latex templates for a phd thesis?

[image]

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to the community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, many users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of the procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a sample of what can be done with `titlesec`, and a few other packages. The  text of the chapter abstract must be written in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{cabin}
\usepackage[nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{TFFrameColor}}
\renewcommand\LettrineTextFont{\color{TFFrameColor}\scshape}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\newcommand*\ftsize[1]{\fontsize{#1pt}{\numexpr 1.2*#1\relax pt}\selectfont}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{framed}
\colorlet{TFFrameColor}{DodgerBlue3}
\renewenvironment{leftbar}{%
\def\FrameCommand{{\color{TFFrameColor}\vrule width 3pt} \hspace{12pt}}%
\MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}
\usepackage[explicit,newlinetospace]{titlesec}%

\def\chapterabstract{\textit{Chapter abstract: } In former days -- that is to say, once upon a time, there lived in the Land of Gramblamble, Seven Families. They lived by the side of the great Lake Pipple-popple (one of the Seven Families, indeed, lived in the Lake), and on the outskirts of the City of Tosh, which, excepting when it was quite dark, they could see plainly. The names of all these places you have probably heard of, and you have only not to look in your Geography books to find out all about them.}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\usefont{T1}{phv}{m}{n}}{%
\parbox[t]{\dimexpr0.12\linewidth-20pt\relax}{\fontsize{48}{48}\selectfont\raisebox{-1.25\height}{\color{TFFrameColor}\thechapter}}}
{1em}%
{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.9\linewidth}\begin{leftbar}{\bfseries\fontsize{24}{30}\selectfont\color{TFFrameColor}
\rule{0pt}{2ex}\strut#1\hfil\vskip2ex\break}\chapterabstract\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{1.5ex}\end{leftbar}\end{minipage}
}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}{6\baselineskip}

\begin{document}%
\setcounter{chapter}{1}

\chapter {Chapter Heading}%

\lettrine[lines=2,loversize=0.1]{I}{n} former days -- that is to say, once upon a time, there lived in the Land of Gramblamble, Seven Families. They lived by the side of the great Lake Pipple-popple (one of the Seven Families, indeed, lived in the Lake), and on the outskirts of the City of Tosh, which, excepting when it was quite dark, they could see plainly. The names of all these places you have probably heard of, and you have only not to look in your Geography books to find out all about them.

Now the Seven Families who lived on the borders of the great Lake Pipple-popple, were as follows in the next Chapter.

\end{document}
```

[image]